# Save NSMutableArray to Parse Object Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to save a NSMutableArray to an array associated with the currently logged in user on my Parse User table but my array doesn't get saved. What am I doing wrong?

This method is called in viewDidLoad()

```
- (void)getSavedLocations {
    if ([[PFUser currentUser]objectForKey:@"Latitude"] == NULL) {
        self.latitudeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.longitudeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    else {
        self.latitudeArray = [[PFUser currentUser]objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
        self.longitudeArray = [[PFUser currentUser]objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
    }
}
```

This method is adds objects to my arrays but the Parse arrays don't get updated with the new data.

```
- (IBAction)saveLocationPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *latString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.myLatitude];
    NSString *longString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.myLongitude];

    [self.latitudeArray addObject:latString];
    [self.longitudeArray addObject:longString];

    [[PFUser currentUser]setObject:self.latitudeArray forKey:@"Latitude"];
    [[PFUser currentUser]setObject:self.longitudeArray forKey:@"Longitude"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to add `[[PFUser currentUser]saveInBackground];`

Comment: could you tell some details about  what's wrong with your code?could you give the right code ?

Comment: There was nothing wrong other than that I needed to add saveInBackground

Comment: YES You had to add The SaveInBackground Function

Answer (score 0):

First check if  self.latitudeArray is NULL in the method saveLocationPressed: ,
if you first save ,then get,you self.latitudeArray may be NULL.
suggest you to lazy load the array like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *latitudeArray;
/**
 *  lazy load _latitudeArray
 *
 *  @return NSMutableArray
 */
- (NSMutableArray *)latitudeArray
{
    if (_latitudeArray == nil) {
        _latitudeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _latitudeArray;
}
```

Comment: I logged it before attempting to set it for the current user and it is not null.